# Why WakefulBroadcastReceiver don't wake my device from deep sleep?

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-wake-lock

I'm traing to wake my device using an WakefulBroadcastReceiver that fires a Service. The service start an Activity and at the end notify WakefulBroadcastReceiver to end the job. I made a log file and i see nothing happening. When i unlock device, after few seconds, activity is starting. Why is not doing when i set the alarm?

Manifest contains BroadcastReceiver and Service declaration and WAKE_LOCK permission.

Here is WakefulBroadcastReceiver:

```
public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    public AlarmBroadcastReceiver() {
        Logging.logToFile("Construct broadcast receiver");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
        startWakefulService(context, service);
        Logging.logToFile("Started wakeful broadcast receiver");
    }
}
```

And here is Service class:

```
public class AlarmService extends IntentService {

    public AlarmService() {
        super("AlarmService");
        Logging.logToFile("Started intent service");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Logging.logToFile("Handle intent service");
        Intent service = new Intent(this, WakeUpActivity.class);
        service.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(service);

        AlarmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Logging.logToFile("Destroy intent service");
   }
}
```

And here is my log:

```
At 2016-04-01 23:14: Alarm set at 23:20 
At 2016-04-01 23:23: Construct broadcast receiver
At 2016-04-01 23:23: Started wakeful broadcast receiver
At 2016-04-01 23:23: Started intent service
At 2016-04-01 23:23: Handle intent service
At 2016-04-01 23:23: Started WakeActivity 
At 2016-04-01 23:23: Destroy intent service
At 2016-04-01 23:25: Alarm set at 23:30 
At 2016-04-01 23:33: Construct broadcast receiver
At 2016-04-01 23:33: Started wakeful broadcast receiver
At 2016-04-01 23:33: Started intent service
At 2016-04-01 23:33: Handle intent service
At 2016-04-01 23:33: Destroy intent service
At 2016-04-01 23:33: Started WakeActivity 
At 2016-04-01 23:34: Alarm set at 23:40 
At 2016-04-01 23:42: Construct broadcast receiver
At 2016-04-01 23:42: Started wakeful broadcast receiver
At 2016-04-01 23:42: Started intent service
At 2016-04-01 23:42: Handle intent service
At 2016-04-01 23:42: Destroy intent service
At 2016-04-01 23:42: Started WakeActivity 
At 2016-04-01 23:43: Started WakeActivity 
At 2016-04-01 23:44: Alarm set at 23:49 
At 2016-04-02 00:02: Construct broadcast receiver
At 2016-04-02 00:02: Started wakeful broadcast receiver
At 2016-04-02 00:02: Started intent service
At 2016-04-02 00:02: Handle intent service
At 2016-04-02 00:02: Started WakeActivity 
At 2016-04-02 00:02: Destroy intent service
```

Edit: And this is how i set the alarm:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SmartClockActivity.this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SmartClockActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Please include how you are setting the alarm

Comment: @DavidMedenjak, done.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a Service and do your processing there. I think most likely your app gets killed, therefore the IntentService that is linked to the Activity that created it, is also killed.
Try with the full Service scope and it must solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it soon as possible.